# Send data from python to nifi http request

Tags: python, http, request, apache-nifi, httplistener

I want to be able to send automatically generated data with random from **`python`** to **`nifi`** using the requests library.
In my python code i put :

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://dev.test.com:7001/contentListener'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
r.status_code
```

> I used HTTP listen from nifi. The configuration is as follows :

[image]

Http Listen don't receive the data ! Can someone help me plz?
Thank you

Comment: What is the output of your program, especially when you print `r.status_code`? Also the URL looks wrong - are you certain your nifi service runs on http://dev.test.com:7001/ ?

Comment: Yes I Find the error in my URL :) Thank you

Comment: Please add more details and errors that you see.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please write and later accept an answer.

Comment: I checked the properties file of nifi and I found that the nifi.web.http.host has the defaut value : localhost and not dev.test.com